# What can I use to monitor memory used by a single program?

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance-monitor

I need to find out how much memory my program is using, at a given moment (i would add objects and see how much the memory is increased... I need this for benchmarking)

I do not have admin rights... (I would need to ask IT to install it, but it would be good if the program did not ask for admin rights to run)

I have tried Task manager but it does not give me a fine enough value - I would also like to be able to select the program whose memory I am watching (filter by it). Any other tools (perfmon) require admin password to run.

Is there anything I can use ?

Comment: Task manager is not only rough, monitoring most of the available columns may even cause harm. Are you sure you know what you're doing? What type of memory would you like to measure?

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The memory used by my program, in real time

Comment: Is it possible for a moderator to move it ? Or should I ask it there too ? (can't delete once an answer has been posted)

Comment: Ok, some basics: never monitor physical memory, never monitor any type of memory with "working set" in the name. Usually "Private bytes" is a good idea to monitor. But since you can't use a real tool due to IT restrictions, I can just wish good luck...

Comment: what would be a "real tool" ? IT has blanket restrictions, but responds to individual requests - if necessary I can make an IT guy sit behind me to input his password every time I need - as long as I have a good tool to use. Is perfmon the best ?

Comment: Real tools: [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/), [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_term=%2Bmemory%20%2Bprofiler&utm_campaign=ANTSMemoryProfiler+%28DE%29&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=sUpEG8FM4|pcrid|60076604052|pkw|%2Bmemory%20%2Bprofiler|pmt|b|pdv|c|&gclid=CPqSscKImsUCFQLMtAodEzYAFw). It depends a bit on the technology used by your program.

Comment: @Thalia Yes, press the "Flag" button and choose the option for moderator attention.

Comment: @KevinPanko We can't vote to close a question and migrate it to any site that isn't on this list: https://i.imgur.com/ja8Iyhy.png

Comment: @Thalia Why don't you build performance monitoring into your application directly?

Comment: @Chipperyman I thought maybe a diamond moderator could migrate to other sites?

Comment: I don't believe they can.

Comment: @Chipperyman - I am using sizeof() to report sizes, but I have objects (some of them built in) containing references, so I need a comparison to see if my reporting is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Windows Resource Monitor? That gives you a lower level of information about resources in use.

If that is not enough, what about [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). That is now provided by Microsoft.

Comment: thank you, Process Explorer is exactly what I remembered using in the past, and is the only one so far I see that shows me resources by application.

Comment: (other than the process tab on Task manager of course - which just didn't seem fine enough). Between the two I can watch lots of counters and get all the info I need.

Answer (score 1):

There is [DTaskManager Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/dtaskmanager_portable)

Comment: would be nice - but usb and cd is disabled.

Comment: @Thalia: download? Have you ever talked to your boss on how you shall get your task done?

Comment: I was reading the instructions on the link and it says i would run the program from usb... I can download it but no usb access

Comment: boss nice - IT evil. Lol

Comment: Try downloading and save in your hard drive, from there run it.